# Which is the reason to release Power Manager onPause?

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code below to keep Cpu on when  i'm in pause mode.
But i read in documentetion that i need to use release onPause mode.

Which is the need to use release on pause mode if i want to keep my cpu always on while mobile is onPause?

## onResume

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

Also every time i'm coming onResume it shows that isHeld is false.
It should show that isHeld is true right?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do any background process when the `Activity` is in `onPause()`.
You can use your service in a `Service` component. See this Page for information about [Services.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Thank you also one last question an activity destroying activity will release my PowerManager? or i need to do it my self?